# IOS Swift how to use background fetch

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift2, uibackgroundmode

Need to implement a background service which will make a web service call and update a record on cloud.
This service should run in all mode of the iPhone app, even if the app is killed and not running (Assume its suspended mode). 
Even when we reboot the phone, it should start the service after reboot.

We looked at background fetch - does this fire when the app is suspended? 
I need it poll every 20 seconds.
Is it possible with background fetch?

Comment: Yeah, background fetch is possible when app is entering in background, but is not called when app suspended

Comment: Also do you know if this will start after phone reboot? Or the user has to launch the app once after reboot so the background fetch starts?

Comment: Polling every 20 seconds is not possible and you wouldn't want to anyway; it will kill the battery. Background fetch executes every couple of hours at most. You should use server initiated push.

Comment: @VikramPote Check this Blog for understand Background Fetch https://blog.newrelic.com/2016/01/13/ios9-background-execution/

Comment: @Paulw11  20 seconds is just an example I took, My real question is if we can make any calls when the app is suspended or not running?

Comment: Suspended yes.  Not running, no.

Comment: Apple recommends push notification for evade of polling when data or something changed. Polling is bad idea for safe battery and usually apple reject this kind of fail.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run any process if your app is killed, Apple dosn't allow to call any type of service after app kill or closed, you can only allow location but you need to give reason to fatch location even app is killed